# Unable to retrieve creatives from DCM

Tags: google-apis-explorer, double-click-advertising

I wrote a script that pulls information about creatives from DCM function described here: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/v3.2/creatives/list

It worked fine for last couple month, however, starting a couple days ago, I began getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
 in /var/www/html/dcm/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/dcm/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 /var/www/html/dcm/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 /var/www/html/dcm/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#3 /var/www/html/dcm/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(779): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/dcm/ in /var/www/html/dcm/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

I have tried using "Try this API" feature to see if anything has changed, and after logging in with Oauth2 I am receiving the following error while trying to list creatives:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Is there something that I need to change on my end, or is this a global issue?